# uWSGI error perl application not found

Tags: perl, uwsgi, dotcloud, dancer

When following the basic setup example for a perl service on dotcloud ("ramen app example") I keep getting a "uWSGI error Perl application not found" when I do a "dotcloud push" and then "dotcloud open" on the dotcloud CLI. It seems that the code push is successful with newly generated URL's but I keep getting the error when I open the URL. This is my first time deploying a perl Dancer application. Any thoughts on how to resolve this? Thanks.

**The steps I took on linux terminal:**

**1. Environment Setup**

```
mkdir ramen-on-dotcloud
cd ramen-on-dotcloud
dotcloud create ramen
```

**2. Created build file "dotcloud.yml "**
and placed it on top root "ramen-on-dotcloud"

```
www:
  type: perl
  approot: helloperl
  requirements:
    - App::cpanminus
```

**3. Generated a sample PSGI application (perl Dancer)**

```
cpanm Dancer
cd ramen-on-dotcloud
dancer -a helloperl
echo "require 'bin/app.pl';" > helloperl/app.psgi
```

**4. Add support for PSGI application by editing makefile.pl and adding Plack in the dependencis.**

```
PREREQ_PM => {
    'Test::More'  =>  0,
    'YAML'        =>  0,
    'Dancer'      =>  1.3113,
    'Plack'       =>  0,
},
```

**5. Push application to dotcloud**

```
dotcloud push
```

6. At this point the code is pushed successfully so I open generated URL's

```
dotcloud open
```

Then I get this error...

> #### uWSGI Error
>
> Perl application not found

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I went ahead, added the steps. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running Step#3 generates the files required for a Dancer project on the fly.  I wonder if it might be this step that's causing the problem you're seeing. It might be related to how `cpanm Dancer` is installed locally.

I've run all the steps and uploaded the working project here: https://github.com/johncosta/example-dancer-on-dotcloud

```
git clone https://github.com/johncosta/example-dancer-on-dotcloud
dotcloud create dancer
dotcloud push dancer
```

Does this yield better results?

Comment: Thank you for the fast response John. I was the same person who submitted the ticket to dotcloud, and you were the one who replied back. Soon after posting the steps I took to get to the error here on stack I realized the issue, and just like you stated it was step 3 that was not playing nice with the cpanm Dancer local installation. I simply skipped the command "cpanm Dancer", and sure enough it created a perl Dancer app on the fly, and was able to open the URL's with no issues at all. Goodbye uWSGI Error :) Thanks John.